# Django returns error 500 for invalid forms

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Probably this is another user error, but I'm having a weird problem with this.

I'm developing a platform and everything works fine if you don't mess with it. Now I'm testing with DEBUG=False and wrong user behaviour like submitting incomplete forms (leaving required fields empty).

The thing is that django (1.3.1) is supposed to return the form errors list automatically if the user sends an invalid form, but instead returns a 500 error for every form in the application.

I think my code is fine, but I'm not sure.

views.py

```
@permission_required('spaces.add_space')
def create_space(request):

    """
    Returns a SpaceForm form to fill with data to create a new space. There
    is an attached EntityFormset to save the entities related to the space. Only
    site administrators are allowed to create spaces.

    :attributes: - space_form: empty SpaceForm instance
                 - entity_forms: empty EntityFormSet
    :rtype: Space object, multiple entity objects.
    :context: form, entityformset
    """
    space_form = SpaceForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    entity_forms = EntityFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
                                 queryset=Entity.objects.none())

    if request.user.is_staff:    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            space_form_uncommited = space_form.save(commit=False)
            space_form_uncommited.author = request.user

            if space_form.is_valid() and entity_forms.is_valid():
                new_space = space_form_uncommited.save()
                space = get_object_or_404(Space, name=space_form_uncommited.name)

                ef_uncommited = entity_forms.save(commit=False)
                for ef in ef_uncommited:
                    ef.space = space
                    ef.save()
                # We add the created spaces to the user allowed spaces

                request.user.profile.spaces.add(space)
                #messages.success(request, _('Space %s created successfully.') % space.name)
                return redirect('/spaces/' + space.url)

        return render_to_response('spaces/space_add.html',
                              {'form': space_form,
                               'entityformset': entity_forms},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('not_allowed.html',
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The template is too big to paste here, you can see it in [dpaste](http://dpaste.org/5jxAB/)

I don't get why django is returning the 500 error instead of showing the error list. Can anybody help me?

The complete source code (it's GPL after all) is on [GitHub](https://github.com/oscarcp/e-cidadania). This modules is on `src/e_cidadania/apps/spaces`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to call is_valid on a form before saving it.

Comment: You can save the form without commiting it to the DB, that way you can modify some fields before validating it, in my case I need to add the user that created the space before validating :)

Comment: O was mistaken, even using commit=False the form can't be saved before validation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ef_uncommited = entity_forms.save(commit=False)
            for ef in ef_uncommited:
                ef.space = space
                ef.save()
```

On the line where it says, ef.space = space. What is space referring to? You haven't defined a name "space" so I'm not sure what ef.space is being set to, is it meant to be the string 'space' or a variable.

Comment: Sorry, space refers to the variable four lines before. It's the saved space object from the SpaceForm

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the HTTP server log to see what the error is. This might help to narrow down the issue. If you are using Apache, the log defaults as /var/log/apache/-error.log.

When unexpected/unexplained 500 errors occur, you can often find more details in the web server error log.

Comment: I'm currently using the django develpoment server :/

Comment: Well a 500 error usually means there is a syntax error in your code or that a model/view is not configured correctly. I would suggest running through each line throwing a custom excteption to see what line the 500 error is occurring on. Add `raise Exception("test")` to the first line and go from there until you see which line/block is causing the 500 error.

Comment: I've located the error in the line `space_form_uncommited = space_form.save(commit=False)`. It seems that the save() does a validation (¿?) even if it has commit=False. How do I avoid that?